# SUMPRODUCT with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I make a sumproduct that include condition?  Like this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(COL1, COL2, COL3="ABC")
```

I tried adding a IF but that didn't work:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(COL1, COL2, IF(COL3="ABC",1,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version with `IF` will work if you "array enter" with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>...... but more usually you use a "co-ercer" like +0 to convert the `TRUE/FALSE` values to `1/0` values, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COL1,COL2,(COL3="ABC")+0)`

[which can be normally entered]

or very commonly

`=SUMPRODUCT(COL1,COL2,--(COL3="ABC"))`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a very useful way to apply a condition for the ranges on a SUMPRODUCT **array** formula, for the case where you would like to apply two conditions(x&y):

`{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(x=range to find coincidences based on x, range to calculate based on conditions found), IF(y=range to find coincidences based on y, range to calculate based on conditions found)))}`

that would look like this:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(C11=$C11:$C500,$I11:$I500), IF(C11=$C11:$C500,$J11:$J500)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

do your mean

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C:C="flag"),A:A,B:B)
```